# Different outputs with fork()

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

can anyone explain why the output of

```
main()   
{   
    printf("hello ");   
    fork();   
    printf("hello ");   
}
```

is:

> hello hello hello hello

and the output of:

```
main()   
{   
    printf("hello\n");   
    fork();   
    printf("hello ");   
}
```

is:

> hello
>   hello hello

what difference does \n make w.r.t to buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `fork` the memory of the process is copied. This includes `stdio` buffers, so if the `hello` stays in the buffer it will be printed by both processes. Both processes go on about their business and eventually flush their buffers and you see "hello" twice.

Now *on most implementations* stdout is line-buffered which means a `\n` triggers a flush. So when the `fork` happens the buffer is empty. A sure fire way to prevent this would be to flush everything before forking.

#### EDIT

> so why does the hello appears twice in the second line of second
>   output

There are now two processes (parent & child) executing the same code so that `printf` is executed twice.

Comment: so why does the hello appears twice in the second line of second output?

Answer (score 2):

While cnicutar's answer describes the mechanism behind what's happening in common implementations, the core issue is that your program is invoking undefined behavior. POSIX places rules on switching the "active handle" for an open file:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01

`fork` is one situation where new handles for a file come into existence, and unless you have prepared for switching the active handle prior to `fork`, it's undefined behavior to use both of them after `fork`:

> Note that after a fork(), two handles exist where one existed before. The application shall ensure that, if both handles can ever be accessed, they are both in a state where the other could become the active handle first. The application shall prepare for a fork() exactly as if it were a change of active handle. (If the only action performed by one of the processes is one of the exec functions or _exit() (not exit()), the handle is never accessed in that process.)

Comment: In other words, the buffer needs to be empty -- ie: the handle needs to be flushed -- before forking, or it's UB.  The `\n` triggers a flush, in the second example...but there's nothing doing so in the first.

Comment: The `\n` only triggers a flush if `stdout` is line-buffered, which only happens if you explicitly set it to line buffering or if it's a terminal.